# Failed to execute Kettle job file by java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, pentaho, kettle

It's my first time to deal with `Pentaho` Data Integration, so i'm trying to execute the job from the java, but i failed to to this ! although of the job is working good from `Spoon`.

this is my code:

```
jobMeta = new JobMeta(LogWriter.getInstance(), "E:\\rubbish\\job.kjb", null);
Job job = new Job(LogWriter.getInstance(), null , jobMeta);
job.start();
job.waitUntilFinished();
```

and this is the result which has an error !:

```
!INFO  01-07 16:32:03,305 - Using "C:\Users\AALKHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\vf
_cache" as temporary files store.
ERROR 01-07 16:32:03,468 - null.0 - Unable to read Job Entry copy info from XML
node : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleStepLoaderException:
No valid step/plugin specified (jobPlugin=null) for SPECIAL

ERROR 01-07 16:32:03,471 - null.0 - org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleStepLoa
erException:
No valid step/plugin specified (jobPlugin=null) for SPECIAL

        at org.pentaho.di.job.entry.JobEntryCopy.<init>(JobEntryCopy.java:110)
        at org.pentaho.di.job.JobMeta.loadXML(JobMeta.java:922)
        at org.pentaho.di.job.JobMeta.<init>(JobMeta.java:726)
        at org.pentaho.di.job.JobMeta.<init>(JobMeta.java:693)
        at ingramint.steps.fullIntStep.step1(fullIntStep.java:62)
        at ingramint.steps.fullIntStep.<init>(fullIntStep.java:32)
        at ingramint.libs.menuLib.mainMenu(menuLib.java:75)
        at ingramint.Main.main(Main.java:24)

Jul 01, 2014 4:32:03 PM ingramint.steps.fullIntStep step1
SEVERE: null
org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleXMLException:
Unable to load the job from XML file [E:\rubbish\job.kjb]

Unable to load job info from XML node

Unable to read Job Entry copy info from XML node : org.pentaho.di.core.exceptio
.KettleStepLoaderException:
No valid step/plugin specified (jobPlugin=null) for SPECIAL


No valid step/plugin specified (jobPlugin=null) for SPECIAL




        at org.pentaho.di.job.JobMeta.<init>(JobMeta.java:734)
        at org.pentaho.di.job.JobMeta.<init>(JobMeta.java:693)
        at ingramint.steps.fullIntStep.step1(fullIntStep.java:62)
        at ingramint.steps.fullIntStep.<init>(fullIntStep.java:32)
        at ingramint.libs.menuLib.mainMenu(menuLib.java:75)
        at ingramint.Main.main(Main.java:24)
Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleXMLException:
Unable to load job info from XML node

Unable to read Job Entry copy info from XML node : org.pentaho.di.core.exceptio
.KettleStepLoaderException:
No valid step/plugin specified (jobPlugin=null) for SPECIAL


No valid step/plugin specified (jobPlugin=null) for SPECIAL



        at org.pentaho.di.job.JobMeta.loadXML(JobMeta.java:968)
        at org.pentaho.di.job.JobMeta.<init>(JobMeta.java:726)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleXMLException:
Unable to read Job Entry copy info from XML node : org.pentaho.di.core.exceptio
.KettleStepLoaderException:
No valid step/plugin specified (jobPlugin=null) for SPECIAL


No valid step/plugin specified (jobPlugin=null) for SPECIAL


        at org.pentaho.di.job.entry.JobEntryCopy.<init>(JobEntryCopy.java:134)
        at org.pentaho.di.job.JobMeta.loadXML(JobMeta.java:922)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleStepLoaderException:
No valid step/plugin specified (jobPlugin=null) for SPECIAL

        at org.pentaho.di.job.entry.JobEntryCopy.<init>(JobEntryCopy.java:110)
        ... 7 more
```

i'm using theses jars:

- kettle-core-3.2.2.jar
- kettle-db-3.2.2.jar
- kettle-engine-3.2.2.jar

so any suggestions please ?

Thank you,

Comment: Is there any reason you aren't at least running kettle 5.0.1? (or even 5.1?)

Comment: yes u r right ! , i used it and it's working now and i added also this code at the start `KettleEnvironment.init();` to avoid some exceptions like `not database found` and `can't read XML input file`.

Comment: I have done the exactly same work this week and it worked. Can you please paste what error you are getting when you are executing the java code when this line is added on top. KettleEnvironment.init();

Answer (score 0):

Once have a look at the code pasted below and it worked. **You need to add all the Jars present in the data-integration/lib to the classpath not only the ones you have mentioned above.**

```
   public class ExecuteJob {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  String filename = args[0];
  KettleEnvironment.init();
  JobMeta jobMeta = new JobMeta(filename, null);
  Job job = new Job(null, jobMeta);
  job.start();
  job.waitUntilFinished();
  if (job.getErrors()!=0) {
    System.out.println(“Error encountered!”);
 } }
  }
```